# Facing issue to find the depth of a kafka topic with SSL enabled port

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm facing issue while finding the depth of a topic in kafka with SSL enabled port by using kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell, but could able to consume the messages from the same port.

However could be able to execute the command to get the depth of a topic for PLAINTEXT port.

Below is the error stack for the same

```
sshuser@wn0:~$sudo bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list wn0.internal.cloudapp.net:9093 --topic TP.TOPIC --time -1 --offsets 1 --security-protocol SSL

{metadata.broker.list=wn0.internal.cloudapp.net:9093, request.timeout.ms=1000, client.id=GetOffsetShell, security.protocol=SSL}
[2017-09-26 19:21:59,026] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(TP.TOPIC)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(0,wn0.internal.cloudapp.net:9093)] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:99)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.readCompletely(BlockingChannel.scala:140)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.receive(BlockingChannel.scala:131)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:84)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:81)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:126)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:59)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:96)
    at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell$.main(GetOffsetShell.scala:98)
    at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell.main(GetOffsetShell.scala)
```

Comment: I would look more at the source code and whether it ever tried establishing an SSL connection. The trace doesnt seem like it.

Comment: As I said in the post I could able to consume the messages with the below command ./kafka-broker/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --topic TP.TOPIC --from-beginning

Comment: The answer will lie then in how you setup the truststores and keystores for each component